# Python program running "else" statement even though previous "if" statement is true

Tags: python

I'm very, very new to computer programming. I started writing a very simple script that gives you directions to someone's house when you input their name:

```
# Users and Directions:
davids_house = "Directions to David's home from X... \n East on Y, \n South on Z," \
               " \n West on A, \n South on B, \n first C on the right."
bannons_house = "bannons directions here"

# Asking the user where he/she would like to go:
destination = input("Where would you like to go? ")

# Reads out a set of directions depending on what name was picked:
if destination in ['Davids_House', 'davids_house', 'Davids_house', 'davids_House']:
    print(davids_house)

if destination in ['Bannons_House', 'bannons_house', 'Bannons_house', 'bannons_House']:
    print(bannons_house)

else:
    print("Sorry, that's not an option.")
```

Whenever I run this program and reach the point where it gives directions, I'll give it a valid input of say 'davids_house'. It will print out the directions, but it will ALSO run the 'else' statement. When I type in an invalid value, it does what I want it to do and ONLY displays "Sorry, that's not an option."

I was under the impression that the 'else' will not run unless the 'if' statement isn't satisfied with a valid value.

I haven't been able to find anything like this, surprisingly, on other forums. I've found questions/answers similar to what I'm looking for, but nothing has actually fixed my issue in this specific case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't read the whole question, but maybe try to use `elif` instead of another `if`

Comment: You've posted a good question. Properly phrased, clear problem statement, etc. Nice work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `if`, and a paired `if/else` that is unrelated to it; sequential `if`s aren't innately related to one another, and an `else` is only tied to one preceding `if` (possibly with multiple `elif` blocks between them). If you want the `else` to only run if all the `if`s fail, you need to tie them together, by making the second `if` an `elif` tied to the first `if`. That will get you mutually exclusive behavior; one and only one block will execute:

```
if destination in ['Davids_House', 'davids_house', 'Davids_house', 'davids_House']:
    print(davids_house)

# Next line changed to elif from if
elif destination in ['Bannons_House', 'bannons_house', 'Bannons_house', 'bannons_House']:
    print(bannons_house)

else:
    print("Sorry, that's not an option.")
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed and I appreciate your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the first two `if` statement in your program are separated and not related, so the second `if` still runs even if the first one was `True`. You should use `if..elif..else`:

```py
if destination in ['Davids_House', 'davids_house', 'Davids_house', 'davids_House']:
    print(davids_house)

elif destination in ['Bannons_House', 'bannons_house', 'Bannons_house', 'bannons_House']:
    print(bannons_house)

else:
    print("Sorry, that's not an option.")
```

Answer (score 1):

It prints the directions to David's house but the `else` only applies to Bannon's house. To make all of them into a single statement, use `elif`:

```
if destination in ['Davids_House', 'davids_house', 'Davids_house', 'davids_House']:
    print(davids_house)
elif destination in ['Bannons_House', 'bannons_house', 'Bannons_house', 'bannons_House']:
    print(bannons_house)
else:
    print("Sorry, that's not an option.")
```

By the way, if you want to include many different forms of capitalization, you may want to pre-process the string before you compare it. A simple example:

```
if destination.casefold() == 'davids_house':
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I also implemented the casefold string method. That was VERY useful!

Comment: @spirebyte. You can always change your selection ;)